# How can I add a cdrom drive letter to a line from cdrecord

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm a newbie working on an windows form application gui for a cmd line program "cdrecord"

I have a combobox, and on form load event I'm display the cdrom drives in the combobox.

cdrecord uses this argument `-scanbus` I have two drives and they display like:

```
'MATSHITA' 'DVD-R UJ-857E ' 'ZA0E' Removable CD-ROM
'HP ' 'DVD Writer 550r ' 'UH23' Removable CD-ROM
```

I also have code to display the drive letter.

How can I add the drive letter to the front of the name cdrecord gives?
Like: D:\'MATSHITA' 'DVD-R UJ-857E ' "first drive"
Like: F:\'HP ' 'DVD Writer 550r ' 'UH23' Removable CD-ROM

here's my entire code. Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
        Imports System.IO
        Imports System.Text

        Public Class Form1
        Public Function FlattenWhitespace(ByVal pText As String) As String
        Dim strFlattened As String

        ' Convert non-space whitespace characters to spaces
        pText = Replace(pText, Chr(160), " ")
        pText = Replace(pText, vbTab, " ")
        pText = Replace(pText, vbCr, " ")
        pText = Replace(pText, vbLf, " ")

        ' Flatten multiple spaces in a row to a single space
        Do
            strFlattened = Replace(pText, "  ", " ")
            If Len(strFlattened) = Len(pText) Then
                ' The length of the string before & after the replacement is the same
                ' This means there is no more replacing to do (i.e. the string is as "flat" as it is going to get)
                Exit Do  ' Quit the loop
            End If
            pText = strFlattened
        Loop
        FlattenWhitespace = strFlattened
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim p As New Process, pStartPath As String
        pStartPath = Application.StartupPath + "\tools\"
        p.StartInfo.FileName = pStartPath + "cdrecord.exe"
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -scanbus"
        p.Start()

        'Takes all the standerd out and puts in a string
        Dim outStr As String = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

        'Splits the output and puts into lines
        Dim listOfLines As New List(Of String)(Split(outStr, Environment.NewLine))

        'Use stringbuilder to remove lines that don't contain CD-ROM
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        For Each LineOfText In listOfLines
            If LineOfText.Contains("CD-ROM") Then
                sb.AppendLine(LineOfText.Trim)
                outStr = sb.ToString
            End If
        Next

        'We have a new list now that just contains our cdrom drives
        Dim s As String() = Split(outStr, Environment.NewLine)

        For Each itm In s

            'Removes extra spaces and chars thats not needed to display nicely in the combobox
            itm = FlattenWhitespace(itm.Substring(itm.LastIndexOf(")"c) + 1))

            ' I have two cdrom drives and they both show on the msgbox
            ' I can't figure out why I'm getting a third msgbox that is empty
            MsgBox(itm)

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(itm) Then
                'Adds itm to combobox1 and is displayed like:  'MATSHITA' 'DVD-R UJ-857E ' 'ZA0E' Removable CD-ROM
                ' And the second drive in displayed like:      'HP ' 'DVD Writer 550r ' 'UH23' Removable CD-ROM
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(itm)
                ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
            End If
        Next

        'gets cdrom drive letter and put it in combobox2
        Dim drvLtr As String
        For Each drive In DriveInfo.GetDrives()

            If drive.DriveType = DriveType.CDRom Then
                drvLtr = drive.ToString
                'My first cdrom drive letter is displayed as D:\
                'And the second one is:                      F:\
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(drvLtr)
                ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: WMI should have the info from the hardware level and the OS level altogether.  As is, it seems like you are going to have to match the strings you collected to something else (probably WMI) to see how they are mapped.

Comment: Why did you add the c# tag? Do you want c# answers?

Comment: Thanks I've used wmi to display and it works, but I was trying to figure out a way to not reference system management, and just use the name cdrecord produces. Could it be done without wmi?

Comment: if you have the drive letter and you know exactly where it goes in the array , then just append. `string final = @"D:\" + driveName;`

Comment: Well, I wanted to use it on different computers. So, the drive names will be different on form load. The cdrecord -scanbus cmd puts out the drives in order, and so does the drive letter code. So I need to figure out how to add the letter to the corresponding drive.